# increase maximum upload file

Tags: uploads

I want to increase the maximum upload file (media default:32mb). Before posting i search, but i didn't have the result that i want.
My host didn't support .htaccess.
I create my own `php.ini` with these:

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 120M
upload_max_filesize = 120M
post_max_size = 100M
file_uploads = On
```

After that i upload in the /wp-admin but i didn't see anything for increase.
Also, i edit the `wp-config.php` with this:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '120M');,
```

even after this i didn't see any change to increase.
How can do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to upload the php.ini file to the document root directory or to the same directory as wp-config.php.

You may also want to modify memory_limit to 120M and modify max_execution_time to 300.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution:

i create a .ini file called: `.user.ini` :

```
memory_limit = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 160M
post_max_size = 160M
max_execution_time = 300
file_uploads = On
```

i upload to the /wp-admin folder, after that I wait about 10 minutes and works.